# Cannot import fonts into R

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, extrafont, hrbrthemes

I'm aware this issue has been posted on already, but I feel like I've tried most of the solutions without finding any success.

I'm using `hrbrthemes` to plot my `ggplot` graphs, and it keeps telling me I don't have the right fonts imported.

I installed all the fonts on windows, I used the `extrafont` packages and ran the `font_import()` command. I keep getting the following errors:

```
C:\Windows\Fonts\RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf : No FontName. Skipping.
```

For absolutely all the fonts. Yet if I go to `C:\Windows\Fonts`, you can see from this image that the `RobotoCondensed` font family is properly installed.

[image]

The `loadfonts(device = "win")` also doesn't do anything for me. I've tried all combinations including restarting my r session in between things and I still get this when I check what fonts are available:

[image]

Here's my session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Switzerland.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Switzerland.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Switzerland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                        
[5] LC_TIME=English_Switzerland.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] extrafont_0.17   hrbrthemes_0.8.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.7        pillar_1.7.0      compiler_4.1.3    later_1.3.0       tools_4.1.3       digest_0.6.29     evaluate_0.15     lifecycle_1.0.1  
 [9] tibble_3.1.6      gtable_0.3.0      pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_0.4.12      DBI_1.1.2         cli_3.1.0         rstudioapi_0.13   writexl_1.4.0    
[17] xfun_0.30         fastmap_1.1.0     Rttf2pt1_1.3.10   stringr_1.4.0     knitr_1.37        systemfonts_1.0.4 gdtools_0.2.4     generics_0.1.2   
[25] vctrs_0.3.8       grid_4.1.3        glue_1.6.0        R6_2.5.1          fansi_0.5.0       RMySQL_0.10.23    pool_0.1.6        rmarkdown_2.13   
[33] farver_2.1.0      ggplot2_3.3.5     purrr_0.3.4       extrafontdb_1.0   magrittr_2.0.1    scales_1.1.1      ggthemes_4.2.4    ellipsis_0.3.2   
[41] htmltools_0.5.2   assertthat_0.2.1  colorspace_2.0-2  labeling_0.4.2    utf8_1.2.2        stringi_1.7.6     munsell_0.5.0     crayon_1.5.0
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: I'm on a mac now so I can't check, but last time I installed fonts in Windows it installed them for my user account in a different folder. Manually moving the font files into `C:\Windows\Fonts` fixed it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The thing is, I checked directly under ```C:\Windows\Fonts``` and they all seem to be properly installed. I just somehow can't get them into R.

Comment: Make sure you actually look at the files. I seem to remember windows showing the font in it's font interface when I looked in the fonts folder, but right-clicking and doing "Get Info" or "Show Details" or something, I could see that the font file was actually in another location.

Comment: I just checked on the properties and they are indeed in the ```C:\Windows\Fonts``` folder

Comment: I had the same issue and Windows makes it incredibly hard to check if the font is there or if it is just a link to the files. I ended up checking with `list.files` in R and the ttf files were not there. I added some more details in my answer.

Comment: So if I run ```View(fonts_df)```, after running ```fonts_df <- sysfonts::font_files()```, I can see all the fonts with the correct path ```C:\Windows\Fonts```. Same if I run list files with the afore mentioned path, they're all correctly listed. I'm really not sure what the problem is. As soon as I run the ```font_import(paths = "C:/Windows/Fonts")```, even if I specify the path it doesn't find them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution to my knowledge is `showtext` and `sysfonts`. First, add the font to the session:

```r
# directly from google fonts
sysfonts::font_add_google("Roboto Condensed")
# or add an arbitrary font with
sysfonts::font_add("Roboto Condensed", regular = "RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf")
```

Once this is done, simply load `showtext` and run `showtext_auto()` once to activate it (you need to repeat `add_font*` and `showtext_auto` every session):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(showtext)

showtext_auto()
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x="Fuel efficiency (mpg)", y="Weight (tons)",
       title="Seminal ggplot2 scatterplot example",
       subtitle="A plot that is only useful for demonstration purposes",
       caption="Brought to you by the letter 'g'") + 
  hrbrthemes::theme_ipsum_rc()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You can also try to make the font available permanently. But it seems to be hit and miss. Theoretically, you need to install the font into `C:\Windows\Fonts`, which you can do by 1) unzip the fonts, 2) right click and "install for all users". If you install the fonts in a different way, there is a good chance Windows will only put a link into `C:\Windows\Fonts`, which R can't deal with.

You can check available fonts with:

```r
fonts_df <- sysfonts::font_files()
View(fonts_df)
```

This works for most fonts in my experience but with Roboto, I still had no luck for some reason. `add_font*` seems to be the best way to go for now.

Comment: Thank you! This works! Quite happy to have a result after trying to get this to work for a couple of hours :) Thanks for the workaround!

Comment: I would consider `showtext` more than a workaround, as it solves many problems base R has with fonts. I would hope these fixes are eventually included into base R.

Comment: Can you use it to pull all the fonts in the ```hrbrthemes``` package? Agreed, I wasn't looking to downplay the solution, I just find it unfortunate given the age of R and the usage of Fonts that it still seems to cause so much aggravation.

Comment: I agree. I only ever used Roboto, but I think all the fonts from the package can be pulled using the same method.

Comment: Alright, I'll keep that in mind if I need more fonts, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and it is really frustrating
As JBGRuber suggested above, it seems that windows renames the font files, but when I use

```
fonts_df <- sysfonts::font_files()
View(fonts_df)
```

They all show up.

At any rate, the way I have been playing around this is:

```
windowsFonts(Robot=windowsFont("Roboto Condensed"))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x="Fuel efficiency (mpg)", y="Weight (tons)",
       title="Seminal ggplot2 scatterplot example",
       subtitle="A plot that is only useful for demonstration purposes",
       caption="Brought to you by the letter 'g'") +
  
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text=element_text(family="Robot",    
                          face="bold", 
                          size=12))
```

[image]

Hope this helps